# Three.js shadow delete

Tags: three.js

I customized Three.js example 'webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html'.
(This file is simple obj file loader)

I want to delete model's shadow.
I erase lines 'scene.add({light})' inside code, then all models be black color.

I want to render model's original texture and original color.
shadow is not required.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what example you are refering to but Object3D class has castShadow and receiveShadow properties, try setting these.

Comment: Thank you @2pha.

I tried these code. but model's are render black color...

`webglRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;`
`canvasRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;`  

`zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );`

`zmesh.castShadow = false;`
`zmesh.receiveShadow = false;`

`for(var i = 0;i < materials.length; i++)`
`{`
    `materials[i].castShadow = false;`
    `materials[i].receiveShadow = false;`
`}`

Comment: Show an image of what you mean. Which renderer are you using? what is in your 'materials' var? receiveShadow castShadow are attributes of object3D not of material.